# Using find in a directory in node.js

Tags: node.js, bash, spawn

I have a function which generate a shell command which use find to delete all files that are not useful anymore:

```
DOWNLOAD_DIR = '/home/user/directory';
function purge(psmil, callback) {
    var arg = [DOWNLOAD_DIR, '\\(', '-name', '"*.mp4"', '-o', '-name', '"*.zip"', '\\)', '!', '\\('],
        file = [],
        i = 0;
        cpurge;

    //Fill file with names of the files to keep

    arg.push('-name');
    arg.push('"' + file[i] + '"');
    i = i + 1;
    while( i < file.length) {
        arg.push('-o');
        arg.push('-name');
        arg.push('"' + file[i] + '"');
        i = i + 1;
    }
    arg.push('\\)');
    arg.push('-ls');
    arg.push('-delete');

    cpurge = spawn('find', arg);

    cpurge.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log('data');
    }
    cpurge.stderr.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log('err: ' + data);
    }
    cpurge.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
        callback();
    }
}
```

Example, it will generate the command:

```
find /home/user/directory \( -name "*.mp4" -o -name "*.zip" \) ! \( -name "tokeep.mp4" -o -name "tokeep2.mp4" \) -ls -delete
```

Which, put in a .sh file and started, work file, it list all .mp4 and .zip in /home/user/directory, print them and delete them

But when I look at the log of my app, it list everything on the disk, and delete all .mp4 and .zip in the directory

Why?

EDIT: Use find directly

I ve tried to use strace, I ve got this line:

```
2652 execve("/usr/bin/find", ["find", "/home/user/directory/", "\\(", "-name", "\"*.mp4\"", "-o", "-name", "\"*.zip\"", "\\)", "!", "\\(", "-name", "\"filetokeep.mp4", "-o", "-name", "\"filetokeep2.mp4\"", ...], [/* 17 vars */]) = 0
```

Comment: Have you tried dumping your ``arg`` list to the console to see what you are actually passing to ``spawn``? Also, your code sets ``file = []`` and then you have ``arg.push('"' + file[i] + '"');`` (with ``i === 0`` at that point) which will push ``"undefined"`` onto your arg list. Also, you could spawn ``find`` directly since there is nothing you do that suggests ``bash`` is needed.

Comment: The comment "//Fill file with names of files to keep" is to shorten the code, when I start reading from file, it have at least 1 argument in it (due to previous codes). I ve outputted arg to the console, to be specific, it s like that that I ve tried to start the command without javascript. (The generatd command is a c/p of my log too)

Comment: I see you tried without bash. See the end of my answer about how you must modify your argument list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### With Bash

When you pass arguments to bash using `-c`, then the argument just after `-c` must contain the whole thing you want bash to run. To illustrate, assuming NONEXISTENT does not exist:

```
$ bash -c ls NONEXISTENT
```

Will just ls all the files in your directory, no error.

```
$ bash -c 'ls NONEXISTENT'
```

Will launch `ls NONEXISTENT` and will give an error.

So your `arg` list must be built something like this:

```
['-c', 'find /home/user/directory \( -name "*.mp4" -o -name "*.zip" \) ! \( -name "tokeep.mp4" -o -name "tokeep2.mp4" \) -ls -delete']
```

The argument that comes after `-c` is the **whole** command you want bash to run.

#### Without Bash

But as I've said in the comment, I do not see anything in your use of `find` that should require you pass it to bash. So you could reduce your `arg` list to just what you want `find` to execute and `spawn` find directly. If you decide to do this, you must not quote the arguments you pass to find. So `"*.mp4"` must become `*.mp4` (remove the quotes), `\(` must become `(`. The presence of the quotes and the slashes are just for bash. If you no longer use bash, then you must remove them. For instance, this:

```
'\\(', '-name', '"*.mp4"', '-o', '-name', '"*.zip"', '\\)', '!', '\\('
```

must become:

```
'(', '-name', '*.mp4', '-o', '-name', '*.zip', ')', '!', '('
```

and the same transformation must be applied to the rest of your arguments.

Comment: I m trying with your way of bash, but look at edit, the find don t work too. It is accepted, but don t prompt anything nor delete anything.

Comment: Look at the last paragraph of my answer about how you must change your argument list when you do not use bash.

Comment: That was that! Thanks you a lot! I m using without bash method